# How to delete last white space in the array when concatenating?

Tags: javascript, whitespace

I need to have a JavaScript alert without the space between last word and exclamation mark.

The final alert should look like:

> I like my own garden verymuchmuch verymuchmuch!

Here is the code with which I have space before.

```
  var inittext, closetext, msg = "";
  var i, j, k;

 var myarray = new Array(3);
 myarray[0] = "my";
 myarray[1] = "own";
 myarray[2] = "garden";

  inittext = "I like "; 
  closetext = "!";

  for (k=0; k < 3; k++) {
    inittext = inittext + myarray[k] + " ";
  }
  for (j=0; j < 2; j++){
    inittext = inittext + "very";
    for (i=0; i < 2; i++){
           inittext = inittext + "much";    
  }
    inittext = inittext +" ";
  } 

  msg = inittext + closetext; 
  alert(msg);
```

Comment: You know that Java and JavaScript are two different languages, right?

Comment: If you actually use arrays, `theIntermediateArray.join(' ')` would be useful and there is no need to 'trim'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check to not add the white space in this way:

```
var inittext, closetext, msg = "";
  var i, j, k;

 var myarray = new Array(3);
 myarray[0] = "my";
 myarray[1] = "own";
 myarray[2] = "garden";

  inittext = "I like "; 
  closetext = "!";

  for (k=0; k < 3; k++) {
    inittext = inittext + myarray[k] + " ";
  }
  for (j=0; j < 2; j++){
    inittext = inittext + "very";
    for (i=0; i < 2; i++){
           inittext = inittext + "much";    
  }
    inittext = inittext + (j<1 ? " " : "");
  } 

  msg = inittext + closetext; 
  alert(msg);
```

or you can just trim the inittex variable `msg = inittext.trim() + closetext;`

Comment: You're welcome, please mark that as the answer for your question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the closetext variable contains the ! and the inittext is where the extra space is added in because of inittext + " " even when there is nothing after the last time that is called, so try

```
msg = inittext.trim() + closetext;
```